# activityIndicatorViewStyle can only be set once?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I can't seem to set the activityIndicatorViewStyle more than once. Here's the code:

```
self.loadingIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 20.0f, 20.0f)];
[self.loadingIndicator setActivityIndicatorViewStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
[self.loadingIndicator setActivityIndicatorViewStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
```

The output is always gray. The second attempt to set the style doesn't seem to make it. Is this a bug?

Comment: Hm. Weird. I am just thinking why you would want them to switch from gray to white. The transition would be immediate, you will not notice it. Anyways... try releasing it before changing style .?

Comment: @Legolas the code above is just for experiment. My real intention is to switch the style when this indicator is inside a popover.

Comment: The `activityIndicatorViewStyle` property is definitely changeable after initialization.  Try with the iOS 5 beta to see if the issue persists.  If it does, file a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I was surprised to see that the `activityIndicatorViewStyle` property is not read only. However, considering that the only documented initializer method is `initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:`, I'm pretty sure the class is intended to be initialized with one style and not to change on the fly.

If you need to switch between the two, I would recommend just swapping out the old one for a new one:

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *newView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorViewStyle:...];
newView.center = self.loadingIndicator.center;
[[self.loadingIndicator superview] addSubview:newView];
[self.loadingIndicator removeFromSuperview];
self.loadingIndicator = newView;
[newView release];
```

Comment: Thanks, that's my suspicion too. Apple should've documented this properly.